# Old links to Mi Yodeya Meta are broken-ish (https)

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, meta

I clicked on the link to Mi Yodeya Meta in [this comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47988/have-any-published-sefarim-referenced-research-done-on-mi-yodeya#comment126656_47988) earlier today, but Chrome wouldn't take me to [`https://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/`](https://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/), because "Your connection is not private."

I assume this is related to the changes in the past few months, with the migration of all the sites to `https`, and changing `meta.judaism` to `judaism.meta`.

Comment: I get the same on Firefox.

Comment: This is still a problem over two years later!