# CYLOR sticky contains a broken link

Tags: bug, status-completed, policy

When the meta sites were changed over from `meta.site.stackexchange.com` to `site.meta.stackexchange.com`, [some links were broken](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4350/) – and, for some reason, this has yet to be fixed nearly three years later.

While usually that's not such a big deal – it's not so often that this problem occurs, and older site users know that they can reach the intended page by exchanging `site` and `meta` in the URL, there's one place where this poses a unique problem: the CYLOR notice, which contains this link behind "*does not offer*": http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734.

Because that's targeted specifically to those who are unaware of the policy, who by and large are new to SE as a whole, all they see is a broken link, rather than the [intended page](http://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734) which actually explains the CYLOR policy.

I probably never noticed it in all this time just because I infrequently use those links, and new users who would notice it don't have enough rep to use meta and alert the powers that be of this problem.

Anyway, I imagine this is a simple fix; can a mod please switch this around at some point?

Comment: When I click on "does not offer" in Chrome on my Android phone, it loads the intended page. Do you see different behavior? In what environment?

Comment: @Isaac https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jhXN.png

Comment: Did this really happen 3 years ago?? Somehow I hadn't noticed until this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about that. The notice on the main site is manually configured and stored in a different spot from posts, so while we did automatically rewrite links in posts, it got missed. Fixed it up now, so it should point to the correct domain going forward.

Also updated the meta post quoting the message since it was using a relative-protocol link and those were apparently also not picked up by the auto-updater.

Please let me know if I missed any other spots.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345952/ – I went ahead and opened a separate page on the main Meta site. I spy in a few places in the help center, as well as literally every comment posted before the change.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy service!